# fswebcam: getting a dataURI via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, raspberry-pi, data-uri

I have fswebcam running on a Raspberry Pi. Using the command line, this saves JPG images.

I now want to receive these images in a Node.js application, and send them on to be used in a browser via dataURI.

On Node.js, I do:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec("fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 160x120 --no-banner --save '-'", function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    var imageBase64 = new Buffer(stdout).toString('base64');
```

I then send `imageBase64` to the browser.

In the browser, setting the received data as the data URI fails:

```
image.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + imageBase64;
```

Doing the above with a data URI created from a stored JPG created by fswebcam (via an online generator) works fine.

What am I not seeing here regarding formats and encodings?

Answer (score 1):

The Content-Type should *probably* be `image/jpeg` and not `image/jpg`.

Also, the `new Buffer(stdout)` is redundant since `stdout` is already a Buffer, so you can just do `stdout.toString('base64')`.

Lastly, if it's the data itself that is bad, you can double-check your base64-encoded output with [this webpage](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/) or by writing `stdout` to disk and using the `file` command on it to ensure it's intact.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 'image/jpg' is fine - tried with data URI encoded elsewhere, and this works. Writing stdout to disk as-is does not give me a valid JPG file - which is what fswebcam produces when I have it write to file instead of stdout. Went via 'uuencode' in the end - which gives me correct output when checking with the recommeded webpage. So thanks for some useful hints!

Answer (score 0):

A little late but as I had same problem while playing with `fswebcam` from Node, the correct way would be to either use ***spawn*** and listen to "data" events on the spawned child's stdout stream. Or if you use ***exec*** then pass the encoding to be "buffer" or *null* as then the stdout argument to the callback will be again a *Buffer* instance, because otherwise by default it's *utf-8* encoded string as stated in the ***exec*** docs

```
child_process.exec("fswebcam -", { encoding: "buffer" }, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        // stdout is Buffer now;
      });
```